# The number of cyclic subgroups of a finite abelian $p$-group related to isomorphism

Tags: group-theory

Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be two finite abelian $p$-groups having the same order and the same number of cyclic subgroups. In this case, it is true that $G_1\cong G_2$?

For such kind of groups, there are some ways to count the number of cyclic subgroups. I tried to prove the statement using the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups and using some explicit formulas to count the number of cyclic subgroups. However, it is difficult to complete the proof using a computational argument. I am pretty sure that the result holds (I have tried it by writing a code and check it for multiple situations). Any idea/hint is appreciated.